# Maven exclusion jar is still part of war file

Tags: maven, maven-3, war, pom.xml

I am using Maven 3.0.5 and I have the following in pom.xml

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>janino</groupId>
                    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

When I build war using `mvn install`, I can see that in war file `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` is also included although I have put `xml-apis` in exclusion list.

Why artifactId which is mentioned in exclusions is part of war file?

How can I make sure that `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar` is not part of war the file?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Is it maybe included through some other dependency?

Comment: @Thilo What is the best way to find out which other dependency is c causing the problem other than individually commenting out one by one?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, you can look at the dependency tree (a tab on the editor for the POM).

Comment: @Thilo I have added `xml-apis` as provided. `xml-apis` is coming from hibernate libraries. E.g. `hibernate-core` has `antlr` and `antlr` has `xml-apis`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at maven dependency description in [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr/2.7.7), I do not see any transitive dependency for antlr.

So this means the retrieved dependencies for xml-apis is coming from some other dependency in your project. Please check if this is the case.

Comment: Shinchan What is the best way to find out which other dependency is c causing the problem other than individually commenting out one by one?

Comment: Check if [this](http://jlorenzen.blogspot.in/2009/06/maven-global-excludes.html) helps.

Comment: Shinchan Your last comment did solve my problem, I have added `xml-apis` as provided. `xml-apis` is coming from hibernate libraries. E.g. `hibernate-core` has `antlr` and `antlr` has `xml-apis`. Thanks for the information.